# Setting permissions to hide menue items in a portlet's options menue in Liferay

Tags: liferay, user-permissions, options-menu

Is it possible in Liferay (6.1.3) to define a user's permissions in a way that it is possible for a user to open a portlet's options dialog (using the wrench icon of the options menue) but restrict the tabs/menue items to bee seen? 
To be more precisely, I have added a configuration tab/menue item within the options dialog of a portlet (resulting in a menue item in the options menue) but this configuration tab/menue item shall be only visible for administrators but not for normal users. 
I added the configuration by using

```
<configuration-action-class>
```

in *liferay-portlet.xml*. Maybe it would be an option to check a user's permissions at the point the options menue is created? What would the appropriate place be in the code?? I guess that should be when the portlet gets visualized?

This is the options menu where I want to hide the two menue items Look and Feel as well as Export/Import.

[image]

Comment: this feature is already there, I mean non-admin user will never see Portlet's option menu[Look and Fee, Configugation etc]

Comment: Yes, but this hides the options menu at all. I just want to hide parts of this menu. 
Is it possible in Liferay to hide menue items from a portlet's options menue (or subsequently hide tabs in the options dialog) depending on a user's role/permissions?
Usually, if you open a portlet's options dialog via the wrench icon you can see some tabs like Look And Feel, Import/Export and so on. Now...is it possible to hide them depending on the current user's role/permissions?